# Possible to do a "dry run" validation of files?

Tags: validation, kubernetes

Before creating an object in Kubernetes (Service, ReplicationController, etc.), I'd like to test that the JSON or YAML specification of the object is valid. But I don't want to actually create the object.

Is there some to do a "dry run" that would be equivalent to running `kubectl create --validate=true -f file.json`, but would just let me know that it passes validation, and not actually create it?

Ideally, it would be great if I could do this via API, and not require the use of kubectl. But I could make it work if it required me to use kubectl.

Thanks.

Comment: Still seems to be a WIP - https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/64830 & https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/5889

Answer (score 43):

This works for me (kubernetes 1.7 and 1.9):

```
kubectl apply --validate=true --dry-run=client --filename=file.yaml
```

Comment: Does this work when you don't have a server connection, I suspect that its not client side which is not helpful in CI situations for validation.

Comment: I added an answer to address this scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61927674/1493439

Comment: `--dry-run=BOOLEAN` has been deprecated. This works instead though. `--dry-run=client`

Comment: Although `--dry-run=client` is a client-side validation, it still requires a server connection: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/51475#issuecomment-673366053

Answer (score 8):

Some kubectl commands support a `--dry-run` flag (like [kubectl run](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_run.html), [kubectl expose](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_expose.html), and [kubectl rolling-update](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_rolling-update.html)).

There is an [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/11488) open to add the `--dry-run` flag to more commands.

Answer (score 3):

There is a tool called [kubeval](https://kubeval.instrumenta.dev) which validates configs against the expected schema, and does not require connection to a cluster to operate, making it a good choice for applications such as CI.

Comment: `kubeval` is discontinued and hasn't been updated for two years. It shouldn't be used anymore. Here is a more update tool: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78071020/16974218

Answer (score 1):

An up-to-date way and local/offline (i.e. without necessary connection to a k8s cluster) way to validate a kubernetes manifest is with `kubeconform`, an open-source project: https://github.com/yannh/kubeconform

Available for install on most package managers (like e.g. on Arch Linux `pacman -S kubeconform`).

After installation, simply run:

```bash
kubeconform mymanifest.yml
```

This will locally validate the yaml file with latest synchronized Kubernetes API schemas.

Answer (score -1):

The use of `--dry-run` and `--validate` only seem to partially solve the issue.

> client-side validation is not exhaustive. it primarily ensures the
>   fields names and types in the yaml file are valid. full validation is
>   always done by the server, and can always impose additional
>   restrictions/constraints over client-side validation.

Source -  [kubectl --validate flag pass when yaml file is wrong #64830](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/5889)

Given this you cannot do a full set of validations except to hand it off completely to the server for vetting.